# Slow Ruby DataMapper.setup

Tags: ruby, postgresql, jruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I found that my Sinatra application was so freaking slow, only happens on `VMWare image on i3`, i don't know why, it doesn't happened on `same VMWare image on AMD APU`, the line that causes the slowness is:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://myuser:mypassword@127.0.0.1/mydbname')
```

it tooks almost 40-45 seconds to run that line wnen on `VMWare image on i3`, and i don't know why, is there any way to overcome this? this happens on `Pry/IRB`, on `Ruby` and `JRuby`.

It doesn't happened when using `active_record` or `psql` command line:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( adapter: 'postgresql', host: '127.0.0.1', database: 'mydbname', username: 'mypassword', password: 'mypassword', port: 5432 )
```

**Ruby** version:  ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]

**PostgreSQL** version: postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.1

**JRuby** version: jruby 1.7.5 (1.9.3p392) 2013-10-07 74e9291 on OpenJDK Client VM 1.7.0_40-b60 [linux-i386]

Comment: Check /etc/hosts - I'm not sure about the specifics around 127.0.0.1 but it may be that for some reason you don't have a localhost entry there and dns lookups are being performed?  Though this should raise unknown host exception.  And 127.0.0.1 is supposed to always be local loopback.

Comment: my /etc/hosts content:
`127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost` and
`::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost`

Comment: the `dig localhost` command are about 5ms, `dig 127.0.0.1` about 0ms..

Comment: What happens if you update your connection string to point at `localhost` rather than `127.0.0.1` - does it make any difference?  Also, are you able to run any sort of packet inspection to see whether there is any evidence of traffic during those 45 seconds?

Comment: i receive no data when `tcpdump 'port 5432' -i lo` when running DataMapper.setup using pry/irb, but receive some data when using `psql -h localhost -U myusername mydbname`

Comment: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` has no difference, still ~45 seconds

Comment: That is very odd.  What postgres jdbc driver are you using?  Also, is there any chance of testing this with ActiveRecord so that you can determine whether it's a driver issue or a system issue?

Comment: i've tried with `active-record`'s `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` completed in less than a second.

Comment: You might want to add that to your original question body.  I'm out of ideas, hopefully someone more knowledgable will be able to step in and help :-)

Comment: As others said that's for sure networking issue: For some reason it your application can't find the localhost/127.0.0.1 right away.

Comment: Time to hit the debugger and step through the DataMapper setup method and see where it hangs.

Comment: after i trace it using pry, yes, the problem was slow `gethostbyname`, so i add one more line `127.0.0.1 myhostname` to `/etc/hosts`, it works fast, only 1 second needed to connect ^^ thank you all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this command solves my problem:

```
echo 127.0.0.1 `cat /etc/hostname` >> /etc/hosts
```